# Scanner has an infinite loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is my class:

```
  public class class1{  
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        File source = new File("E:\\NUS_WID_Tags\\All_Tags.txt");
        File target = new File("fiche1Filtered3.txt");
        int i=0; 

        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(source);
            PrintStream psStream= new PrintStream(target);
            while (s.hasNext()) {                   
                System.out.println(i++);
            }                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The program enters an infinite loop.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to consume the actual input.  [`hasNext` doesn't consume the input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29).

> The scanner does not advance past any input.

Insert a call to `next()` in the loop:

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String str = s.next();
    System.out.println(i++);
}
```